# ssh ignores ssh-agent

Tags: ssh, fedora, openssh

I'm using a new system and `ssh` is ignoring my `ssh-agent`.  Note I've been doing this for years elsewhere, it is not a new thing I am confused about.  With `bash`:

```
> echo $SSH_AGENT_PID
1234
> echo $SSH_AUTH_SOCK
/tmp/ssh-foo/agent.1234
> ps -p 1234
  PID TTY          TIME CMD
 1234 pts/12   00:00:01 ssh-agent
```

So, ssh-agent is clearly running and the appropriate environment variables are in place.  I've also verified the socket is actually there.

```
> ssh-add key
Enter passphrase for key: [done]
Identity successfully added.
> ssh-add -l
1024 SHA256:[blah] key
```

So the key has been added. But:

```
> ssh -i key me@there
Enter passphrase for key:
```

***PARDON?***

I've diff'd `/etc/ssh/ssh_config` with one from my previous system (!#$% upgrading...) and they are identical.  According to the distro (fedora 23) package meta-info this one is openSSH version 7.1p1, previous installs I've used are no newer than 6.6.

The problem doesn't exist for all users, leading me to believe it might be some new security feature. Does anyone know what's up?

Comment: Can you add any relevant output from `ssh -vvv ...`? It may have clues as to why it refused to read from the agent.

Comment: @JeffSchaller  That solved it -- it is a new feature (see my answer).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It is a new feature, presumably for 7.x. It required adding the key type to `/etc/ssh_config` using this option:

```
PubkeyAcceptedKeyTypes +ssh-dss
```

RSA keys are accepted by default (see `man ssh_config`), which is why it worked in one case but not another (being root was a red herring factor and I've removed this from the question).

Note again that option is not in my previous `ssh_config` nor in the corresponding man page (openssh v. 6.6).