# `ssh-agent` asks passphrase after it has been added

Tags: ssh-agent

I'm new to the `ssh-agent` and encounter what I identify as a "*bug*".

### Situation

- I have a passphrase-protected private key.
- I want to use the `ssh-agent` so I do not write the passphrase each time I `ssh`.
- `ssh-agent` adds the private key (according to `ssh-agent -l` displaying the private key).
- **yet** when I try to `ssh` to the remote server with the private key (thanks to the `~/.ssh/config` file), the **`ssh-agent` still asks for my passphrase**!

### Environment

I'm on fedora `Linux 4.5.7-202.fc23.x86_64 #1 SMP Tue Jun 28 18:22:51 UTC 2016 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux` with the `ssh` version being `OpenSSH_7.2p2, OpenSSL 1.0.2h-fips`.
Here are two sequences that do not work using the (what I think) GNOME 3 keyring agent and the `ssh-agent`.

Here is the `~/.ssh/config`:

```
 IdentitiesOnly yes
[..]
Host root.w.com
    HostName 92.1.2.3
    User user
    Port 22
    IdentityFile /home/user/.ssh/key-rsa.priv
```

#### GNOME 3 keyring agent

```
user@local:~$ ssh server-key
Enter passphrase for key '/home/user/.ssh/key-rsa.priv': 
You have new mail.
Last login: Sat Aug 13 10:41:46 2016 from some.ip.dot.org
user@remote:~$
Connection to <remote-ip> closed.
user@local:~$ echo $SSH_AUTH_SOCK
/run/user/1000/keyring/ssh
user@local:~$ echo $SSH_AGENT_PID

user@local:~$ ssh-add ~/.ssh/key-rsa.priv
Enter passphrase for /home/user/.ssh/key-rsa.priv: 
Identity added: /home/user/.ssh/key-rsa.priv (/home/user/.ssh/key-rsa.priv)
user@local:~$ ssh-add -l
4096 SHA256:aZl81hzUczH+sX+/5+tCJHln11xqta62RbtzLQt5LKE /home/user/.ssh/key-rsa.priv (RSA)
user@local:~$ ssh server-key 
Enter passphrase for key '/home/user/.ssh/key-rsa.priv': 
✘  user@local:~$
```

#### `ssh-agent` agent

```
user@local:~$ eval $(ssh-agent)  
Agent pid 3169
user@local:~$ echo $SSH_AGENT_PID
3169
user@local:~$ echo $SSH_AUTH_SOCK
/tmp/ssh-nqpXUUf2qNpT/agent.3168
user@local:~$ ssh-add -D
All identities removed.
user@local:~$ ssh-add ~/.ssh/key-rsa.priv
Enter passphrase for /home/user/.ssh/key-rsa.priv: 
Identity added: /home/user/.ssh/key-rsa.priv (/home/user/.ssh/key-rsa.priv)
user@local:~$ ssh server-key 
Enter passphrase for key '/home/user/.ssh/key-rsa.priv': 
✘  user@local:~$
```

---

### Question

- What should I do so the `ssh-agent` do not ask the passphrase?
- Any idea why does these not work?

My issue is similar to [this question](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/245183/ssh-ignores-ssh-agent) though I read the answer and the solution did not work for me.

Comment: Please also post the appropriate `Host` section of your `~/.ssh/config`, sanitized if you wish.

Comment: Added in **Environment** section.

Comment: Hmm, stupid question: Does it work without `IdentitiesOnly`? Also, is the name on your ssh command line (`server-key`) different from the name in the config (`root.w.com`) on purpose?

Comment: Sorry for the `server-key`  and `root.w.com` confusion. It actually the same server and user, the only diff is the algorithm used to generate the keys. Also: **I confirm that without the `IdentitiesOnly` _it works_ ! ** Just put your comment into an answer, and I'll validate it. Add an explanation and I'll +1 it !!

Comment: @Auzias, `IdentitiesOnly` should instruct the client to only use those keys given in `IdentityFile` commands, but not others the agent may have. Here, though it seems that you _are_ setting the relevant key with `IdentityFile`, and if that is the case, I don't know why it doesn't work as it should. It's as if the key loaded to the agent was different from the one listed in the config file. And referencing the same key with a different filename isn't enough, the actual key needs to be different for `IdentitiesOnly` to skip it.

Comment: I see, would you like to post it as an answer so my question can be tagged as answered?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As @ilkkachu said, the issue is `IdentitiesOnly`.

In you `Host` section, just add

```
IdentitiesOnly no
```

Comment: What if I do no want my ssh client try every single key for each host?

Comment: @Auzias, if you put the above in the root.w.com section of your config, then _only_ root.w.com will use all possible Identities, the rest will still follow your original "IndentitiesOnly yes" directive.

Comment: Can someone explain why ? That drives me nut. it works for me everywhere except on a specific linux server. Why a key added to ssh-agent is not used by the system if IdentitiesOnly is set to yes ???

Answer (score 7):

I just discovered that `IdentitiesOnly` seems to need the public key on the local machine to works properly.

Without the public key on the local machine, I was always prompted for the passphrase even if the private key was in the agent and of course the public key on the remote machine.

The public key path is the same as the private key path with `.pub` append.

Comment: I run into exactly this behaviour. Thx for your answer. Both will solve this issue:
1. Add public key files to ~/.ssh or 
2. remove/uncomment  IdentitiesOnly in ~/.ssh/config